# C# VScode bug? "not all code paths return a value" keeps showing up, despite everything being right

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I've this function:

```
public async Task<ServiceResponse<string>> ChangePassword(string username, string password, string newPassword)
{
    var device = await dataContext.Devices.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Username.ToLower().Equals(username.ToLower()));
    if (device == null || device.Password != password)
        return new ServiceResponse<string> {
            Success = false,
            Message = "Invalid Credentials"
        };
    device.Password = newPassword;
    await dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    
    return new ServiceResponse<string> {
        Success = true,
        Message = "Password changed"
    };       
}
```

Either I'm drunk or there's nothing wrong with it. But still, there's a red line underneath the function definition stating:

> MainService.ChangePassword(string, string, string)': not all code paths return a value

Even weirder is that, if I run the project, eveything compiles successfully....

Comment: As an aside, it looks like you've got unencrypted passwords hanging around? DO NOT DO THIS EVER! If you don't know how to properly secure passwords, use a library which does

Comment: Could it be that whatever VScode is using to validate syntax is not fully up to date? There is no problem with that method regarding that error message.

Comment: Only thing wrong I see here, and it's a major issue if you ask me, is that you've apparently stored passwords in cleartext. Unless "Password" is a fancy word for "salted hash of password" then **you really should not be doing that!** That's not a compiler issue though, that's more of a "don't be an idiot" thing.

Comment: @canton7, Thank you. I'm dully aware, but my senior told me to do it this way

Comment: Then he's not a senior, except perhaps in age. I'm sorry, but there really is **no excuse** these days, unless this is a throwaway prototype demo application just to get started with something.

Comment: I've been getting similar issues with VS2019. Telling me I have errors then running absolutely fine. My fix was remove a resource then relink it.

Comment: Or do a rebuild instead of a build.  Note that, if the project continues to run after "not all code paths return a value," then it is a warning, not an error.

Comment: I guess it's just the code analysis/intellisense going berserk here for some reason. Try to rebuild. Or to restart VS Code. If the issue persists, please let us know.

Comment: @BartHofland, you're right. I restarted VS code and the warning is gone. Guess I should control my panic before coming crying to SO.